# Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.route.params.text)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I followed React Navigation Doc to pass params to my previous screen, but i'm getting error when acces it in my previous screen saying

> evaluating this.props.route.params.text

```js
export default class SelectMap extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
      }
    render(){
        const {text} = this.props.route.params
        return (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MapView')}>
                    <Text>
                        Open Maps
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {text}
                    </Text>
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>       
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

This is how i sent the params

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectMap', {text:JSON.stringify(this.state.marker)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because this code `const {text} = this.props.route.params` didn't run when you navigate back to your previous screen

I think you can use `callback` function instead

```
export default class SelectMap extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
      }
    render(){
        const [text, setText] = useState(""); // change to state
        return (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
// use callback
this.props.navigation.navigate('MapView', { onTextSelect: (text) => {
                    setText(text)
                } })}>
                    <Text>
                        Open Maps
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {text}
                    </Text>
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>       
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the error got in when i open the screen for the first time before I navigate to next screen

Comment: Yeah, I usually didn't use route.prams in this case. If you still want to use it, consider add null checking

Answer (score 0):

your constructor must be as below

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```